# Why is silver considered a "type 1" metal although it has multiple oxidation states?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, metallurgy

I noticed that the metals I learned were "type 1" back in early chemistry class as they have one oxidation state including silver, aluminum, zinc, and cadmium. However, those metals weren't reported as "type 1" when I looked online. I noticed that although silver has three oxidative states, it is still listed as "type 1" metal. Does anyone know why we still categorize it as "type 1" or have an insight into what is still considered a "type 1" metal?

Comment: I just looked it up: Type 1 has a single oxidation state, type 2 has multiple. If you look hard enough, many metals have more oxidation states than you learn in intro.

Comment: Furthermore, the main oxidation number of silver is +1. Compounds with higher oxidation number are rare, not very stable, and difficult to obtain.

Comment: What is this classification? I haven't heard of this. Can you provide a brief explanation of this classification basis?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't heard of this classification of metals before. Anyways, the below image is from [a nomenclature handout](https://www.amherst.edu/media/view/226859/original/Chem11%2B1011F%2BD1%2BNomenclature%2Bhandout.pdf) where silver has been considered "type 2" metal:

[image]

It's true that silver has oxidation states other than +1 but those are rarely encountered. So, it can get confusing and most of time, we may tend to consider that silver has only one oxidation state leading to it falling into "type 1" metal.

Comment: I am upvoting, since you took the time to post a valid answer, but I am now going to deliberately forget about ‘type 1’ and ‘type 2’ because they serve no needful purpose now, if they ever did at all.

Comment: @EdV I found the source: Zumdahl's Introductory Chemistry: A Foundation , Fifth Edition. Here is a web version of one of the [tables](https://college.cengage.com/chemistry/intro/zumdahl/intro_chemistry/5e/shared/templates/mediaactivities/tables/table05-2.jpg).